# import google font or local in next js with tailwind

Tags: css, next.js, fonts, tailwind-css

with imported local font but  font doesn't work and there are a warning in browser console say:

postcss-import-parser: Unable to find uri in "@import sakal from "./sakal.ttf""

when main.css is :

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@import sakal from "./sakal.ttf";

* {
  @apply font-sakal !important; 
  font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
}
```

and tailwind.config.js is :

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: false,
  theme: {
    fontSize: {
      xs: '0.75rem',
      sm: '0.875rem',
      base: '1rem',
      lg: '1.125rem',
      xl: '1.25rem',
      '2xl': '1.5rem',
      '3xl': '1.875rem',
      '4xl': '2.25rem',
      '5xl': '3rem',
      '6xl': '4rem',
    },
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sakal: ['sakal']
      },
...

i
```

tried to install next/font and import google font not worked

main.css :

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amiri:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap');

* {
  @apply font-amiri !important;
}
```

Comment: If you are using `next/font` see the documentation which also includes a Tailwind demo. You should import the font in your `_app.js`. https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts